# How to get record with count?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to get the total of registered members of each building.

**Member Model:**

```
public function count_all($buildingId)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $buildingId);
        $query = $this->db->get('building_members');
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

**Member Table Rows**

Id

building_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `count_all_results()`

1).This will be count all records from table

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results('building_members');
```

2).This will be count rows on specifice condition

```
 $this->db->where('id', $buildingId);
 $this->db->from('building_members');
 echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Comment: Not working, I think I 'm entering the code on wrong file :( Just little bit confused.  Can you please guide me?